# Colon in FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following line in my vba code

```
[A1].FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],Rates!A:H,3,FALSE),"""")"
```

When run, it creates this in Excel:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A8,Rates!A:(H),3,FALSE),"")
```

I'm not sure why 'H' shows up in parentheses. Of course the formula doesn't work. When I remove the parentheses, it does work. But how do I get VBA to create the formula correctly in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is very simple actually. On one hand you are saying `.FormulaR1C1` and on the other you are using both notation. Stick to either `R1C1` or `A1`

So try this

```
[A1].FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[7]C,Rates!C:C[7],3,FALSE),"""")"
```

or

```
[A1].Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A8,Rates!A:H,3,FALSE),"""")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to write VLOOKUP with VBA runs into weirdness like this a lot for some reason.  The best way to work around that is to write code to name the range, then use that name in the VLOOKUP.

```
ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="VLRange", RefersTo:="=Rates!" & Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1)).Address
```

Then your formula-writing code is

```
[A1].FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],VLRange,3,FALSE),"""")"
```

Comment: `runs into weirdness like this a lot for some reason..` There is nothing weird about it :) VBA like any other programming language tries the best to it's ability to execute what you tell it to. If you issue a wrong command, it will either error out or give you errornous results.